# Use Sonar with Objective-C language definition

Tags: objective-c, sonarqube

I've found a [blog post](http://deadmeta4.com/2011/05/17/objective-c-copy-paste-detection-using-jenkins/) that describes how to use CPD on an Objective-C project. The author also provided a [CPD language library for ObjectiveC](https://github.com/jkennedy1980/Objective-C-CPD-Language/). Unfortunately, the GUI provided by the Violations plugin in Jenkins is rather ugly. The visualization that Sonar uses is much more helpful in analyzing the code.

The following command is used to generate the corresponding CPD output:

```
java
-Xmx512m
-classpath pmd-4.2.5.jar:ObjCLanguage-0.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.CPD
--minimum-tokens 100
--files [Path to XCode project classes]
--language ObjectiveC
--encoding UTF-8
--format net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.XMLRenderer > cpd-output.xml
```

As far as I know, the project language can be configured in the Sonar plugin configuration at Jenkins. But how can I tell Sonar to use the `ObjCLanguage` library? I only need this for detecting code duplication and visualization by Sonar (since it is so much prettier).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have analysis results in Sonar, you need to install a Sonar plugin that brings support for the language. However, there's currently no plugin for Objective-C, so you won't be table to get what you're trying to achieve... unless you develop this plugin! ;-)

Comment: Thank you! So there is currently no way to make Sonar aware of the language definition above by adding it do some class path? It would be great if it would just work with the CPD command as above. The other results wouldn't be necessary at this time.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not as simple as adding a JAR to the classpath. However, if you just want copy-paste detection for Objective-C, writing a very basic Sonar plugin shouldn't be difficult. You can have a look at our documentation (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Coding+a+plugin) and our code examples (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/sonar-reference-plugin).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be ongoing work on an Objective-C plugin for Sonar. You may find it at https://github.com/fhelg/sonar-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

I have also seen another Objective-C plugin for Sonar:
https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c

Comment: It's the same repo as @jgongo posted.